# Recommended books that describe emission and absorption of light and light/matter interactions

Tags: electromagnetism, optics, resource-recommendations, quantum-optics

Hello I am a Chemical Engineer that has ventured into the field of optics and I was wondering if there is any recommended book/books to understand the maths and also some answered exercises or examples to familiarize myself with their application. My ultimate goal is basically being able to apply the equations to estimate properties and then compare it with the experiments.